# javascript for loop construct ordered list with colored circled on the numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I construct an ordered list from a `for loop` and get a color hex value for each item in the loop. I want to circle the number using the item color.

JS bit:

```
var MY_COLORS = ['#8b0000', '#555','#666','#777', '#008b00', ....];

for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    list +="<li>"+  "<div style='background-color:"+MY_COLORS[i]+";width: 25px; height: 25px;border-radius:50%'></div>" + items[i]+"</li>";
}
$("#myList").append(list)
```

html bit:

```
<div class="panel">
    <ol id="myList"></ol>
</div>
```

I want my numbers be like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/j2gK8/

but the colors should be taken from the `MY_COLORS[i]` inside the loop.
How can I construct my list and pass it to the div element so that the numbers are colored as explained?

Comment: inline style is still a thing!

Comment: @Erazihel it is not related at all to that post, mine is related to css issues rather...

Comment: The problem is that the color in your example is added to the pseudo element, and you can't target pseudo element directly with jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/j2gK8/882/

```js
var MY_COLORS = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 'black']

$('ol li').each(function(i){
 $(this).find('.circle').css({
   background: MY_COLORS[i]
  }).html( i+1);
});
```

```css
ol {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 26px;
    list-style: none;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    counter-reset: numList;
}
ol li {
    width: 176px;
    margin-right: 44px;
    float: left;
    position: relative
}
.circle {
    counter-increment: numList;
    content: counter(numList);
    
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: -26px;
    
    font: bold 12px sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 18px;
    
    width: 18px; height: 18px;
    background: #f0f;
    
    -moz-border-radius: 999px;
    border-radius: 999px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
    <li><div class="circle">
    
    </div>List item number one has some text to go along with it.</li>
    <li><div class="circle">
    
    </div>List item number two has some text to go along with it as well.</li>
    <li><div class="circle">
    
    </div>List item number three has some text to go along with it too, what did you expect?</li>
    <li><div class="circle">
    
    </div>List item number three has some text to go along with it too, what did you expect?</li>
    <li><div class="circle">
    
    </div>List item number three has some text to go along with it too, what did you expect?</li>
    
</ol>
```

You can't target **pseudo elements** using JavaScript or jQuery.
So you need a work around.

I have added a div with class **circle** and manipulated the background color and text in Javascript

Hope this will help you!!!

Comment: this is actually what i want! my for loop is in a js file and my color array is also there, so when I put it there, it doesn't work. I don't want to separate them. By the way, I have other list on the page, so I want to target it using the element ID, which is `#myList` . Could you suggest fixes?

Comment: Here you go with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/j2gK8/883/ . . Let me know if you are looking for the same...  Here in this fiddle I have 2 list with unique ids. So I targeted only one list & updated the background color for numbering circle.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var MY_COLORS = ['#8b0000', '#555', '#666', '#777', '#008b00'];
var items = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
var list = "";
for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
  list += "<li>" + "<div style='background-color:" + MY_COLORS[i] + ";width: 25px; height: 25px;border-radius:50%;text-align:center;color:#fff'>"+items[i] + "</div></li>";
}
$("#myList").append(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <ol id="myList"></ol>
</div>
```

```js
var MY_COLORS = ['#8b0000', '#555', '#666', '#777', '#008b00'];
var items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];
var list = "";
for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
  list += "<li>" + "<div style='background-color:" + MY_COLORS[i] + ";width: 25px; height: 25px;border-radius:50%'></div>" +"<span style='color:"+MY_COLORS[i]+";'>"+items[i]+"</span>" + "</li>";
}
$("#myList").append(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <ol id="myList"></ol>
</div>
```

Modified from @Abhishek Pandey,
is this you trying to achieve ?

Comment: yes i know, my problem is not the colors array!!
please read carefully the question, my problem is to color each number in the list with a different color.

Comment: And from where must come colors?

Comment: @CarnaruValentin i updated the question, it is simple, the colors are inside an array, and that array holds as much as colors needed for my lists, so there is always enough! I just want to color the numbers of the list using that color.

Comment: </div>" + items[i]+"</li>";
is 'items[i]' print the number you means ?